# jQuery wait for Ajax request until it's done doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a formular, when I press a button I have to handle a async Ajax request. The function `nextButtonHandler()` should be called after all processes from `requestForTariff()` are finished. I tried touse the following, but it didn't wait until the request processing is over.

```
$.when(requestForTariff(requestType.Street)).done(function(){
    nextButtonHandler()
});
```

Here is my Ajax function:

```
function requestForTariff(requestParam) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: //...,
        data: getRequestJSON(requestParam),
        success: function(data, status) {
            if (status == "success") {
                if (requestParam == requestType.Street) {
                    handleResult(data);
                }
                //...
            }
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        error: // ...
    });
```

Comment: `requestForTariff()` doesn't return a Promise (Deferred)

Comment: Also, you don't need `$.when` if you only pass one argument. If you didn't use it the error would have been more apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Adreas comment, changing my `requestForTariff()` function to

```
function requestForTariff(requestParam) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: //...,
        data: getRequestJSON(requestParam),
        success: function(data, status) {
            if (status == "success") {
                if (requestParam == requestType.Street) {
                    handleResult(data);
                }
                //...
            }
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        error: // ...
    });
```

solved my problem.